# Does visual studio check Xaml static resource on compile time?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I often use static resource as converter in XAML, e.g.

```
Visibility="{Binding ShowAdditionalView, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

and I declare

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

This works most of the time, but if say, I mistype BooleanToVisibilityConverter, or forgot to add the declaring line, my program still compiles and I get nasty exception in runtime that's hard to debug.

Is there any way to tell VS to check for such problems? I have VS 2010 Express

Answer (score 0):

Straight from [MSDN: Debugging Silverlight XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg181270%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> **Static resource references are evaluated at XAML load time.** The order in which individual XAML components are loaded is important. One common failure of resource lookup is making a forward reference: where the StaticResource reference to a key is made prior to the item definition of an item with that x:Key value. **At design time, Visual Studio can show highlighting and place warnings in the error list for cases where a StaticResource reference does not resolve to an existing key in any resource dictionary.** Visual Studio also accounts for application-level resources, so that references from a page to an application resource do not produce false warnings.